# push array data and find the index of array

Tags: php

how can i create a empty array that i can push users information such as:

```
$users->set('bob', array('email' => 'bob@site.com', 'password' => '123456'));
$users->set('joe', array('email' => 'joe@site.com', 'password' => 'test'));
```

and retrieve/read the keys i want to read like:

```
$user = $users->get('bob');
echo 'Bob, your email is ' . $user['email'];
```

and also be able to retrieve all key names

```
$keys = $users->getKeys();
```

i have searched google but nothing worked right. Please show me how so i can learn more..

PS: It would also be nice to learn how to delete keys from the array like:

```
// Delete a key
$users->delete('joe');
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `$users['bob'] = array(...)`?

Comment: i need a system, but what does $users contain? what did you define it as

Comment: To do it with your syntax, you need to define a class. The class contains an array property, and the `get` and `set` methods access the array using normal PHP syntax.

Comment: could you show mw without a class ( get, set)

Comment: You can't do it without a class. The `->` syntax only works with classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use ordinary array syntax:

```
$users['bob'] = array('email' => 'bob@site.com', 'password' => '123456');

$user = $users['bob'];

$keys = array_keys($users);

unset($users['joe']);
```

Comment: Pefect, you sir are mr. Perfect! thanks it what i need

Comment: But how do i store the whole  array holder: $users ? when i do: 
    $users['bob'] =  array('email' => 'bob@site.com', 'password' => '123456');
    
    $users['nana'] = array('email' => 'bob@site.com', 'password' => '764634664');
    
    
    $data= $users;
    
    $user = $data['nana'];
    
    
echo 'Bob, your email is ' . $data['password']; it does not work

Comment: I've Never Seen Mr.Barmar Giving Wrong Answer. Lots Of Knowledge. God Gifted Brain. +1 For You Sir.

Answer (score -1):

Learn array_keys() function on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

```
$keys = array_keys($users);
```

Comment: How does this help with `->get` and `->set`?

Comment: $arr['xxx'] = 'yyy' - set value, 
$arr['xxx'] - get value